# Extract pictures that have no extension name from an APK

Tags: android, apk, extract, android-image

I'm really new to this: I want to extract the images from an APK to create a wikia game guide, but all the images in the library folder don't have an extension. I have tried renaming them so that they have common extensions that have tranparency (as I know the images have transparency in the game) like .png .swf .tiff, .bmp and .jp2 and none of those make valid files, I mean, files that can be opened by my computer.

Since the images have no format in their folders, I imagine there is some software in the app itself that does the image processing and displaying. I'm wondering how I can find it (in what type of folder or extension I'd find it) and how I could then convert such images to png.

Here's a sample of a formatless "image" as I could find it in the lib folder. It's from a game app called "Fantastic beasts and where to find them". https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jOghd11GXFX1ROUUd2UV90bE0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Contact the developers of the APK. Ask to license their artwork, with a condition that you get the artwork in conventional file formats.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an asset from the game engine Unity, version 5.

**Hint:** First bytes in text are UnityFS followed by what version of assets bundles it is etc.
Recognise a) "game" b) "unity" => (well known professional game engine) and Google for UnityFS and voila...

You will likely need a matching version of Unity to read that, possibly also the [asset bundle manager extension](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/45836).